# Display categories of products in the shipment grid

Tags: magento-1.7, product, category, orders, grid

I want to display the categories of products in the shipment grid.

Suppose a shipment contains 3 products- **A,B,C.**

I want to display the categories of all the 3 products, separated by **";"** in the shipment grid.

I am able to display the products names and SKU by joining the table `sales_flat_order_item`.

How can I achieve this ?